# Why do we suddenly forget things, like PIN or phone numbers, that we've known for years?

Tags: brain, memory

Is it common to forget a 4 or 5 numeric code which has been used extensively for months and well remembered?

There's an article on the [guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2007/aug/20/money.comment) describing this phenomenon and by the number of comments it seems quite common yet no scientific aspect trying to solve the mistery.

Is it some common phenomenon of the brain? Some erasing of irrelevant numeric things happening during sleep?

Answer (score 2):

Forgetfulness is a common phenomenon that tends to increase with age. It usually affects short term memories but it can affect long term ones too. Here are some possible causes which I quote from [Healthline](http://www.healthline.com/symptom/memory-loss) (the full list available at that link):

> - sleep deprivation
> - use of alcohol or drugs and some prescription medications
> - lack of oxygen to the brain
> - migraine

It can happen at any age and it is normal if (quoting Deane Alban, [Memory Loss: When It’s Normal and When It’s Serious](http://bebrainfit.com/lifestyle/drains/memory-loss-normal-serious/)):

> Are you overworked and stressed out? Are you eating poorly? Are you on a low-fat diet or skipping meals to lose weight?  Do you struggle with insomnia? Do you drink too much?
>
> If you answer “yes” to any of these questions, it’s likely you are losing your memory because your lifestyle is catching up with you.

You mention loss during sleep in your question. Sleep affects memories (see [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/sleep-deprivation-effects-on-memory) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_and_memory)):

- deprivation of sleep leads to memory loss
- during sleep brain selects *relevant* information gathered during the day and turns it into memories
- certain stages of sleep improve memories